# ChartJs (ver: 2.8.0): Custom tooltip does not hide if clicked (or mouse pointer is moved) outside the chart canvas area

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

I am using ChartJs (ver: 2.8.0) to render line chart with **custom tooltip that would be visible on `click` event of the points.**

The issue is that the custom tooltip does not hide when mouse pointer is moved outside the chart canvas area.

To make the tooltip visible only on click event of the points, in the chart options I have made the chart to respond only on click events like this:

```
options: {
  events: ['click'],
.....
..
```

**Please let me know if above is the correct way to show tooltip on click event and not any other events.**

With this, both the default chart js tooltip and custom tooltip does not get hide by itself when mouse is moved (or clicked) outside of the chart canvas area.

Can anyone please help me with the solution?

Here is the [link to my JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/bn3kvjr8/)

Below is my full code:

**JS:**

```
var lineChartCustomTooltip = function (tooltip) {
  // Tooltip Element
  var tooltipEl = document.getElementById("chartjs-tooltip");

  if (!tooltipEl) {
    tooltipEl = document.createElement("div");
    tooltipEl.id = "chartjs-tooltip";
    tooltipEl.innerHTML = "<table></table>";
    this._chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
  }

  // Hide if no tooltip
  if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }

  // Set caret Position
  tooltipEl.classList.remove("above", "below", "no-transform");
  if (tooltip.yAlign) {
    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltip.yAlign);
  } else {
    tooltipEl.classList.add("no-transform");
  }

  function getBody(bodyItem) {
    return bodyItem.lines;
  }

  // Set Text
  if (tooltip.body) {
    var titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
    var bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(getBody);

    var innerHtml = "<thead>";

    titleLines.forEach(function (title) {
      innerHtml += "<tr><th>" + title + "</th></tr>";
    });
    innerHtml += "</thead><tbody>";

    bodyLines.forEach(function (body, i) {
      var colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];
      var style = "background:" + colors.backgroundColor;
      style += "; border-color:" + colors.borderColor;
      style += "; border-width: 2px";
      var span =
        '<span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="' + style + '"></span>';
      innerHtml += "<tr><td>" + span + body + "</td></tr>";
    });
    innerHtml += "</tbody>";

    var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector("table");
    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
  }

  var positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
  var positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;

  // Display, position, and set styles for font
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
  tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + "px";
  tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + "px";
  tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._bodyFontFamily;
  tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.bodyFontSize + "px";
  tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._bodyFontStyle;
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + "px " + tooltip.xPadding + "px";
};

var options = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "# of Votes",
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "red",
        pointBackgroundColor: "red",
      },
      {
        label: "# of Points",
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "blue",
        pointBackgroundColor: "blue",
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    events: ["click"],
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false, // disable the default tooltip
      custom: lineChartCustomTooltip, // use the custom tooltip
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            reverse: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js Line Chart - Custom Tooltips",
    },
  },
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chartJSContainer").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
canvas { background-color : #eee;
}

#chartJSContainer {
    border: 1px solid;
}

canvas {
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
    }

    #chartjs-tooltip {
      opacity: 1;
      position: absolute;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
      color: white;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
      transition: all .1s ease;
      pointer-events: none;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }

    .chartjs-tooltip-key {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
Just by adding `mouseout` event to the chart `events` option, I got it resolved.

The custom added tooltip now hides when mouse is moved or clicked outside the chart area.

**Code:**

```
options: {
  events: ["click", "mouseout"],
....
...
```

Here is the [link to my updated JS Fiddel example.](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/bn3kvjr8/15/)